# Split screen in to 3 sections

Tags: javascript, html

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           Header section
------------------------------------------------------------------------
              Left Section        |         Right Section
                                  |        
            Table                 |           Table 
            of                    |            of
            Contents              |           contents  
                                  |
                                  |  
                                  |  submit
```

Sorry what I'm asking is very novice but I never found any page explaining how to split the screen in above format. I went thru multiple questions on stackoverflow and other forums but didn't found one.

Also, for the right section there is a text box called "Comments" to which the users can give their input and once they hit the submit button, their input should be captured and displayed in the same page.

I'm not sure how to achieve

Comment: doesn't this help - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp ? You just need to google 2 column layout in css

Comment: a `div` with some height and the next 2 `divs` with width `50%` and `float : left`

Comment: You might want to take a look at  [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: You can even look into [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/).

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: Yes You're right sir !

Comment: Bootstrap is well worth a look as Rajesh has said because it inlcudes media queries for responsive mobile views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using a layout like this:

```css
.container {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.top {
width: 100%;
height: 20%;

background-color:green;
}

.bottom {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
}

.split {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

.left {
background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top</div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left split">left</div>
    <div class="right split">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another method would be to use flexbox, but flexbox has a funny way of resizing children.

Comment: Perfect thank you..

Answer (score 2):

By using `flexbox`, you can simply achieve it. But one issue is that, browsers like IE 11 don't support `flexbox`. So check the compatibility issues and go on.

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

main, header, section {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

section div {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <section>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Much appreciate your input here +1.